# Foursquare - Less venue response results when using the endpoints 'venues/explore' than 'venues/search'

Tags: php, jquery, foursquare

We have checked the venue results in two cases using php foursquare api,

**Case 1:** Endpoints 'venues/search'

```
            $params = array("ll"=>"34.149087500000000000,77.538450700000000000","intent"=>"browse", "radius"=>"99000","limit"=>"100");
            $response   =   $foursquare->GetPrivate("venues/search",$params);
            $recents = json_decode($response);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($recents);echo "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

```
    Venue count is 50.
```

**Case 2:** Endpoints 'venues/explore'

```
            $params = array("ll"=>"34.149087500000000000,77.538450700000000000","radius"=>"99000","offset"=>"0","limit"=>"100");
            $response   =   $foursquare->GetPrivate("venues/explore",$params);
            $recents = json_decode($response);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($recents);echo "</pre>";
```

**Result:**
        Venue count is 4.

For the above two case,  We have  used the same latitude and longitude in params. 50 venues are returning when we use the endpoints 'Venues/Search' but only 4 venues are returning when we use the endpoints 'Venues/Explore'. Why the venues are mismatching by using the endpoints 'Venues/Explore'.

Answer (score 0):

from my personal experience with trying to define these endpoints someone from the Foursquare API team explained it like so:

The explore mode is more of a "what are some interesting places around me right now?" whereas search is better for something like "i know there's a coffeeshop nearby somewhere, let me find it".

I hope that give you a little further insight.

--EDIT--

Also further to reading the api, without specifying a section for the explore endpoint the default fallback query is 'coffee shop', while search will just return you up to 50 results from all venues in your specified radius.